# HTML5 LocalStorage or AppCache

Tags: html, local-storage, html5-appcache

G'day,

I am am trying to work out whether it is possible to cache / store locally different files for different users using the HTML5 data storage API's. I am working on a project where we would like to have offline access to PDF documents. Now I can do this sucessfully using the appcache manifest file and explicitly add a file in there, but the issue is that different users need different files cached / stored locally.

Can anyone shed some light as to whether this is even possible?

Cheers

Comment: It's possible if you can generate a different manifest file for different users, but it's not really what appcache was designed for.

Comment: Agreed, the pdf files are downloaded to the client anyway, so why not just give them the pdf files they will need offline?

Comment: @mattdlockyer I'm trying to do almost the exact same thing.  The users already have the PDF files, but the site I've made provides a nice search interface for metadata that is external to the PDFs.  Why use a web site for this?  I already had a web site that served the PDFs over the internet, so (it's 2015, for goodness sake) it should be easy to toggle some flag that makes them get served from the user's computer instead.

Comment: @Daniel one thing I'm investigating for this use case is using some client-side program to intercept requests to some folder on the server and serve up from a folder on the file system instead.